# jena query RDF turtle, I have a prefix followed by other prefixes

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, turtle-rdf

I have to parse RDF data given in the lemon format, it's all ok but I can't have access to one field that moreover is the most that I need.

The needed field is `lvont:nearlySameAs`, I would like to take only one of the subsequent values (they are all the same more or less) but if there is only a method to take them all is not a big problem.

this is a piece of the rdf:

```
@prefix lemon: <http://lemon-model.net/lemon#> .
@prefix lvont: <http://lexvo.org/ontology#> .
@prefix wordnet-ontology: <http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/ontology#> .
@prefix mcren: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/EN/> .
@prefix mcrgl: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/GL/> .
@prefix mcres: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/ES/> .
@prefix mcrca: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/CAT/> .
@prefix mcreu: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/EU/> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix gawnl: <gawn-lemon/> .

<00000003-n> a wordnet-ontology:Synset ;
    rdfs:label "aardvark  n"@eng ;
    rdfs:label "arcán talún"@gle ;
    wordnet-ontology:part_of_speech wordnet-ontology:noun .

<arcán_talún-n> a lemon:LexicalEntry ;
    lemon:canonicalForm <arcán_talún-n#CanonicalForm> ;
    wordnet-ontology:part_of_speech wordnet-ontology:noun .

<arcán_talún-n#CanonicalForm> a lemon:Form ;
    lemon:writtenRep "arcán talún"@gle .
<arcán_talún-n> lemon:sense <arcán_talún-n#1-n> .

<00000003-n> lvont:nearlySameAs mcreu:eus-30-02082791-n ,
                       mcrca:cat-30-02082791-n ,
                       mcres:spa-30-02082791-n ,
                       mcrgl:glg-30-02082791-n ,
                       mcren:eng-30-02082791-n .
<arcán_talún-n#1-n> a lemon:LexicalSense ;
    wordnet-ontology:sense_number 1 ;
    wordnet-ontology:old_sense_key "aardvark%1:05:00::" ;
    lvont:nearlySameAs <http://lexvo.org/id/wordnet/30/noun/aardvark_1_05_00> ;
    lemon:reference <00000003-n> .

<00000003-n> wordnet-ontology:synset_member <arcán_talún-n#1-n> .
```

and this is my query:

```java
    final String query =
            "prefix lemon: <http://lemon-model.net/lemon#> \n" +
            "prefix lvont: <http://lexvo.org/ontology#> \n" +
            "prefix wordnet-ontology: <http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/ontology#> \n" +
            "prefix mcren: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/EN/> \n" +
            "prefix mcrgl: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/GL/> \n" +
            "prefix mcres: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/ES/> \n" +
            "prefix mcrca: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/CAT/> \n" +
            "prefix mcreu: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/EU/> \n" +
            "prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> \n" +
            "prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> \n" + 
            "prefix gawnl: <gawn-lemon/> \n " +
            "\n" +
            "select ?lemon ?sense ?nsas where {\n" +
            "  ?lemon a lemon:Form ;\n" +
            "             lemon:writtenRep ?sense ;\n" +
            "             lvont:nearlySameAs ?nsas .\n" +
            "}";
            ;
```

I can retrieve first two values but if I add the third row the query produces no output. Clearly there is something I'm doing wrong but I can't figure out what to change. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED QUERY**

```
            final String query =
                "prefix lemon: <http://lemon-model.net/lemon#> \n" +
                "prefix lvont: <http://lexvo.org/ontology#> \n" +
                "prefix wordnet-ontology: <http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/ontology#> \n" +
                "prefix mcren: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/EN/> \n" +
                "prefix mcrgl: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/GL/> \n" +
                "prefix mcres: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/ES/> \n" +
                "prefix mcrca: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/CAT/> \n" +
                "prefix mcreu: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/EU/> \n" +
                "prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> \n" +
                "prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> \n" + 
                "prefix gawnl: <gawn-lemon/> \n " +
                "\n" +
                "select ?wr ?nsas where {\n" +
                "  ?le  a lemon:LexicalEntry  ;\n" +
                "         lemon:canonicalForm ?cf .\n" +
                "  ?cf  a lemon:Form  ;\n" +
                "             lemon:writtenRep ?wr .\n" +
                "  ?le    lemon:sense ?sense . \n" +
                "  ?sense a lemon:LexicalSense ; \n" +
                "           lemon:reference ?ref . \n" +
                "  ?ref     lvont:nearlySameAs ?nsas. \n" +
                "  FILTER regex(str(?nsas), \"eng\")." +
                "}";
```

With this last query i can retrieve the entire URI `lvont:nearlySameAs mcreu:eus-30-02082791-n...` now the final step should be to add the prefix

```
@prefix mcren: <http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/EN/>
```

to obtain only one value ( instead of using the filter) but at the moment I cannot figure how to do this.

Comment: Adding a prefix to the query doesn't change anything. You can restrict resources in the result only by particular properties of them. In your case, the only thing is to use a filter either with a `REGEX` or the function `STRSTARTS(STR(?nsas), "http://lodserver.iula.upf.edu/id/WordNetLemon/EN/")`

Comment: ok thanks I didn't think of filtering the entire URI, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only query data that exists. Please have a look at the data again and you'll see that the only resource `arcán_talún-n#CanonicalForm` that matches the first two triple patterns of your query

```
?lemon a lemon:Form ;
       lemon:writtenRep ?sense .
```

by the triples

```
<arcán_talún-n#CanonicalForm> a lemon:Form ;
    lemon:writtenRep "arcán talún"@gle .
```

But for this resource there is no triple with the predicate `lvont:nearlySameAs` in your data. Thus, there is no connection in the data and your query pattern doesn't match. If you only want the values for that property, simply write a query that consists of a pattern that matches the data.

I don't think that this is what you want, but

```sql
SELECT ?nsas WHERE {?s <http://lemon-model.net/lemon#nearlySameAs> ?nsas } LIMIT 1
```

would simply return one value, yet it doesn't look useful to me.

### Update: a more complex and connected query by the sense would be

```sql
PREFIX lemon: <http://lemon-model.net/lemon#>
PREFIX lvont: <http://lexvo.org/ontology#>

SELECT ?lemon ?sense ?nsas WHERE {
  ?lemon a lemon:Form ;
         lemon:writtenRep ?sense .
  ?sense lemon:reference ?ref .
  ?ref lvont:nearlySameAs ?nsas .
} LIMIT 1
```

Comment: ok, I see, but this file has been generated someway so there should be a method to retrieve that kind of information... in the bottom part there is a field `lemon:reference <00000003-n>`  that is linked to the filed `lvont:nearlySameAs`...

Comment: Ok, I see. I updated my answer. The idea is to go via the sense and the reference. For the future, simply think of it as a graph and which edges you have to traverse. Hope this helps.

Comment: ok thanks, i had to rework a little your solution to obtain something close to what i want, now final step missing. I have updated the original post